# How to parse kubernetes logs with Fluentd

Tags: fluentd

I use few services in EKS cluster. I want the logs from 1 of my services to be parsed

kubectl logs "pod_name" --> this are the logs when I check directly in the pod service

**2022-09-21 10:44:26,434 [springHikariCP housekeeper    ] DEBUG HikariPool                     - springHikariCP - Fill pool skipped, pool is at sufficient level.
2022-09-21 10:44:36,316 [springHikariCP housekeeper    ] DEBUG HikariPool                     - springHikariCP - Before cleanup stats (total=10, active=0, idle=10, waiting=0)**

This service has java based login (Apache Commons logging) and in kibana at the moment is displayed whole log message with date and time + Log Level + message :
[image: kibana logs from my service]

Is it possible this whole log to be parsed into the separate fields (time and date + Log Level + message) and displayed in the Kibana like that.

This is my fluentd config file for the source and pattern:

```
<source>
      @type tail
      path /var/log/containers/*background-executor*.log
      pos_file fluentd-docker.pos
      tag kubernetes.*
      read_from_head true
      <parse>
        @type multi_format
        <pattern>
          format json
          time_key time
          time_type string
          time_format "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%NZ"
          keep_time_key false
        </pattern>
        <pattern>
          format regexp
          expression /^(?<time>\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2} \d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}.\d{3})\s+(?<level>[^\s]+)\s+(?<pid>\d+).*?\[\s+(?<thread>.*)\]\s+(?<class>.*)\s+:\s+(?<message>.*)/
          time_format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%N%:z'
          keep_time_key false
        </pattern>
      </parse>
    </source>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to just update the filter as per need

```
<filter **>
@type record_transformer
enable_ruby
<record>
foo "bar"
KEY "VALUE"
podname "${record['tailed_path'].to_s.split('/')[-3]}"
test "passed"
time "${record['message'].match('[0-9]{2}\\/[A-Z][a-z]{2}\\/[0-9]{4}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\\s
+[0-9]{4}').to_s}"
</record>
</filter>
```

you have to parse the **record** & **message** with data something like if between [0-9] or [A-Z] same way show in above example.

Edit the `filter.conf`

You can create your own **Key** and **value**, in value you have to parse the filed and **flutenD** will populate the value.

Comment: Hi Harsh, I just found that log record has this value. record={"log"=>"2022-09-21 13:50:36,587 [springHikariCP housekeeper ] DEBUG HikariPool      - springHikariCP - Fill pool skipped, pool is at sufficient level.\n", "stream"=>"stdout"}  So actually first key is the whole message that is displayed in kibana and (time and date + Log Level + message) are sent like a values of key1. They are not separated key values. It will work with the same solution that you wrote? Or it is impossible to be created 3 separate fields (date, log level and message) because they are part of same key

Comment: you can give it try and test i think it will work.